# How can I Join a Skype for Business Web Conference?

Tags: skype, webco

I have customers who are using Skype for Business for web conferencing (meetings). In the past I've been able to join these from a browser, but recently it started to force the use of a .msi plugin that won't work in Linux (for obvious reasons). I can obviously run a VM for these, but it would be better to join natively.

https://tel.red/linux.php has a Linux client, but it's $49/US per year. They have a free version, but I have not been able to get a straight answer on whether I can join a meeting with the free version as a guest without any time limitations. I don't care about initiating screen sharing or video, or even audio (I can use a dial-in number). I just want to know if I can see the customer's screen without paying for their service.

Have you used this solution? can you share your experience? Do you have any other ideas for how to do this?

And not using Skype for Business meetings is NOT an option if that's what my enterprise customers are using :-)

Comment: I was looking for the same feature since long time ago now, I never found anyway :-(

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sfb-mso_other/skype-for-business-for-linuxubuntu-platform/4e1e78b7-e7db-4446-950f-85941db601e5 Interesting discussion, lovely comments. I think it's time to move to better products (and there are lots of them) .

Comment: Issue is that one can't often dictate or negotiate with what's on the other side.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is here:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1248342/1064531

Yes it is just using a VM which you already mention.  However I found that it works pretty damn well this way. My laptop has NVMe SSD, 8 cores and 16GB RAM so I can easily spare 2 cores and 4GB to boot a Win 10 VM in seconds, and copy/paste a skype4B link directly in, as well as drag and drop any Office files to share screen.

The shared clipboard and drag and drop support in VirtualBox allow it to work seamlessly. Audio, Mic, and webcam can be passed through to VM seemlessly too. I have used this method for a long time for work, never had an issue.  Give it a shot, you will be surprised.

Answer (score 0):

I use Pidgin(+SIPE plugin). With some hacks I also managed to fix conf autojoin by http links. See my [github](https://github.com/kakash1hatake/lync-conf-join)